# SQL Server view to show results of API call?

Tags: sql-server, xml, rest

We have several stored procedures in SQL Server that we would like to start to include XML from a Rest API. Is it possible to create a SQL Server VIEW that will query a rest API that is outputting XML format?

Thank you

Comment: No you can't do this in a view. You could do it in a stored procedure though. But I would question why you want to have a query make an API call. Something sounds a little funny there.

Comment: @SeanLange we have data that is available through an API that we want to query against in a procedure. The procedure is called several different ways and by making the change in one spot it would minimize changes across other integrations.

Comment: Why not have your API simply call a stored procedure. Then you can consume it directly in sql server without the crazy amount of effort required to call an API which is basically just executing some query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make the view in SQL Server and use as a normal table in your controller, just like this:

```cs
return context.(Your_View).ToList();
```

Comment: Please re-read the question, the OP wants to display the results of an API call in a SQL Server view, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm using sql views to retrieve data from sql